# How can I match the array values (e.g values from i++) to the keys in arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

`I am trying to get this output. I have a db table where i have saved store opening hours and closing hours from monday to sunday. I am able to get the record on the browser but i am trying to sort that dates against the day. If today is friday, then friday should be shown first and then following rest of the week. The code is:

```
<?php

$wdays = array( 0 => "Monday" , 1 => "Tuesday",  2 => "Wednesday", 3 => "Thursday",  4 => "Friday", 5 => "Saturday", 6 => "Sunday");

$times = array(
   0 => date( $row_DetailRS1['monO'] ). " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['monC'] ),
   1 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['tueO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['tueC'] ),
   2 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['wedO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['wedC'] ),
   3 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['thurO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['thurC'] ),
   4 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['friO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['friC'] ),
   5 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['satO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['satC'] ),
   6 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['sunO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['sunC'] ) );

$combine = array_combine($wdays,  $times);

$html = "<table>";
$html .= "<tr><td>Sl.No</td><td>Days</td><td>Business Hours</td></tr>";
$i = 0;

while (true) {
    if ($i === 7) break;

    if ($datetime->format('N') === '7' && $i === 0) {
        $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
        continue;        
    }

    echo  $datetime->format('D') . $listItem[1]   . "<br/>";
    $listItem = array('<li>', '</li>');    

    $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
    $i++;

    echo "Value for i: ".$i. "and the day is: ". $datetime->format('D') . "<br/><br/><br/><br/> " ;

}

foreach ($combine as $wdays =>  $times):

    $html .= "<tr>";
    $html .= "<td>". $datetime->format('D')."</td>";
    $html .= "<td>".$i."</td>";
    $html .= "<td>".$times."</td>";
    $html .= "</tr>";

    $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
    $i++;

endforeach;
$html .= "</table>";
echo $html;
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly so that it's readable

Comment: Hi,Andrew, 

I hope the code is readable now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have cracked it:)

so here it goes:-

```
 <?php
  $datetime = new \DateTime();

  $listItem = array('<li class="active">', '</li>');



  $times = array(
    1 => date( $row_DetailRS1['monO'] ). " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['monC'] ),
    2 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['tueO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['tueC'] ),
    3 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['wedO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['wedC'] ),
    4 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['thurO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['thurC'] ),
    5 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['friO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['friC'] ),
    6 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['satO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['satC'] ),
    7 =>  date( $row_DetailRS1['sunO'] ) . " ". date( $row_DetailRS1['sunC'] ) );





  $html = "<table>";
  $html .= "<tr> <td>Days</td> <td> </td> <td></td>   <td>Business Hours</td></tr>";
  $i = 1;





  foreach ($times as $key => $value):



    $m = $datetime->format('N');


      $html .= "<tr>";
      $html .= "<td>". $datetime->format('D')."</td>";
      $html .= "<td>". " "."</td>";
      $html .= "<td>". " "."</td>";
      $html .= "<td>".$times[$m]."</td>";
      $html .= "</tr>";

      $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));



      $i++;




  endforeach;
  $html .= "</table>";
  echo $html;



 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use foreach on $combine,
you just want a loop like this: (I think this will work):

```
    for ($i=0;$i<7;$i++)
        $html .= "<tr>";
        $html .= "<td>". $datetime->format('D')."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$i."</td>";
        $html .= "<td>".$combine[$i]."</td>";
        $html .= "</tr>";

        $datetime->add(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
    endfor;
```

Comment: Hello SilicaGel, thanks for the response, 

the code is working but cant get the values in the array. It is only returning as:-

fri 7

but the value i want is like:-

Fri  09:00:00 17:00:00
Sat 10:00:00 17:00:00  
Sun 11:00:00 16:00:00
Monday 10:00:00 18:00:00  
Tuesday 09:00:00 17:00:00  
Wednesday 09:00:00 17:00:00 
Thursday 09:00:00 17:00:00

Comment: Hi, sorry, using a for loop won't work.  It was late when i wrote that.  Can you try duplicating your previous while loop, then echo $combine[$datetime->format('N')] (That should use the right key)

Comment: Hi SilicaGel, sorry for late reply. I still not able to get the correct way I needed. Its not working for me. Can u please help me. thanks